# Mechanize page.search does not work with link.click method

Tags: css, ruby, web-crawler, nokogiri, mechanize

I have a shop page and want to see all articles as a link first. After that, I want to crawl the content of each link. I'm getting the links as follows:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(page_URL)
article_links = page.search('div.sklep-produkt h3 a').attr('href')
```

I'm using search with CSS since it's the easiest way for me to search for an exact tag or an area. If i put a `puts "#{article_links}"` I can already see a link, so it' working. However, I want more than one link - all article links - from the page so I'm using this:

```
article_links.uniq { |link| link.uri }.map do |link| #no double entries
    link.click
    target_URL = page.uri + link.uri
    puts "#{target_URL}"
end
```

The problem is that methods like uniq, map, link.click, uri and so on don't work with page.search. Example error:

```
undefined method `uri' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x0055a7a4a7e440> (NoMethodError)
```

It's only possible with `page.links_with(...)`.
How do I crawl multiple links with `page.search`?

Comment: have you tried storing the links in an array and then iterating over that with an `agent.get` on each link, something like  `links_array.each {|link| agent.get link }`? I think you can add a block to the `.get` too. I tried Mechanize and switched instead to much easier Watir, so know Mechanize  hardly at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like...

```
# find the links
article_links = page.css('div.sklep-produkt').css('h3').css('a')

# store in a new array, and take out the un-uniques
unique_article_links = article_links.map {|l| l.attribute('href').value }.uniq

# visit each link and do whatever needs to be done
unique_article_links.each do |link|
  agent.get(link) do |l|
    #... do stuff here
    p l.css('title').text
  end
end
```

I tested this on Wikipedia and it returned titles ok for me:

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page'
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(url)

article_links = page.css('div#mp-tfa').css('a')
unique_article_links = article_links.map {|l| l.attribute('href').value }.uniq

unique_article_links.each do |link|
  agent.get(link) do |l|
    #... do stuff here
    p l.css('title').text
  end
end
```

What's happening is it's returning a Nokogiri object and not an array, so you have to take the values you want from the Nokogiri object and put in a fresh array, then you can use Array methods.

Comment: I'm still getting errors like
undefined method `uniq' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x0055ab97844958> (NoMethodError)

or when I remove uniq:
undefined local variable or method `links' for Crawler:Class (NameError)